# Override Store View … "Enable Product" with "Use Default Value" for all Products

Tags: magento2, database, products

It has probably happened by import the `products`, that `Magento 2` in the Store view `"DE"` set its own value - `" Enable Product " is checked`  - and no longer uses the "Use Default Value".

Is it possible to fix about the database to set the value `Use default value` for all products in Store View `DE`?

Which `Tables` I have to `change`?